# Misaligned side by side pictures - how to resolve?

Tags: graphics, floats, vertical-alignment

I am trying to put 4 figures but they are getting missaligned. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/Mountaincar/mountaincar.pdf}
    \caption{Episode returns for best runs} \label{fig:comp_best}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/RiverSwim/Riverswim12.pdf}
    \caption{Episode returns for all runs} \label{fig:comp_all2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/DeepSea10.pdf}
    \caption{POMD episode for different $\beta$} \label{fig:comp_all}
  \end{subfigure}
 \label{fig:comp1}
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/deepsea-Msensitivity.pdf}
    \caption{POMD episode for different $\beta$} \label{fig:comp_all1}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

This gives me this
[image]

Comment: First ensure that all the figures have identical dimensions and that the surrounding whitespace embedded in each figure is the same. Also consider aligning the subfigure captions with [b].

Comment: Make sure padding is exactly the same in all images at least where you want to keep the caption. If you want a row of two images to be aligned, you might need to move each group of two images into one of the boxes, e.g. `minipage`, or `parbox`, etc. I tried your code and it seems aligning everything, based on `example-image` files from `graphicx`.  BTW your code doesn't compile due to the missing package `graphicx`.

Comment: If you use the `floatrow` package, you'll have tools to align both captions and figures.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to align the tops of the images and align the captions separately.  This uses a tabular.

I found previous examples aligning the tops and using a tabular, but not both.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% adds [valign=...]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{duckuments}% novelty only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[tp]% h not supported
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=top]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/Mountaincar/mountaincar.pdf}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=top]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/RiverSwim/Riverswim12.pdf}
    \\
    \subcaption{Episode returns for best runs}\label{fig:comp_best}
    &
    \subcaption{Episode returns for all runs}\label{fig:comp_all2}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=top]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/DeepSea10.pdf}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=top]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/deepsea-Msensitivity.pdf}
    \\    
    \subcaption{POMD episode for different $\beta$}\label{fig:comp_all}
    &
    \subcaption{POMD episode for different $\beta$}\label{fig:comp_all1}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{One typically also gives a caption to the figure as a whole}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small variation of nice @joh answer (+1):

- for inserting of images is used `\adjincludegraphics`
- by `\adjustboxset` is determined size of images
- consider is default baseline of image (at their bottom)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{xcolor}         % colors
\usepackage[aboveskip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% adds [valign=...]
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{duckuments}% novelty only

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[tp]
    \captionsetup{skip=-1ex}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,valign=bottom}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/Mountaincar/mountaincar.pdf}
    &\adjincludegraphics[height=33mm]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/RiverSwim/Riverswim12.pdf}
    \\
\subcaption{Episode returns for best runs}\label{fig:comp_best}
    &   \subcaption{Episode returns for all runs}\label{fig:comp_all2}  \\
\adjincludegraphics[height=33mm]{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/DeepSea10.pdf}
    &\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}%{RLSVI-optimistic-sampling/Figures/DeepSea/deepsea-Msensitivity.pdf}
    \\
\subcaption{POMD episode for different $\beta$}\label{fig:comp_all}
    &   \subcaption{POMD episode for different $\beta$}\label{fig:comp_all1}
\end{figure*}
See \ref{fig:comp_best} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]