# Center alignment of images but with captions aligned at bottom

Tags: graphics, align, captions, vertical, horizontal

I have two different figures that I want to center align in a figure environment and I want the captions aligned at the bottom. Both figures have different sizes (see attached).[image: Figure 1] [image: Figure 2]

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can include both in the same `figure` environment with a single `caption` below it.

Comment: You can do that very simply with the `floatrow` package

Comment: @Sigur I am trying to write a subcaption for each one and align them.

Comment: @Bernard could you give me an example? or maybe redirect me to another answer easy to understand?

Comment: @el_maxx, oh, sorry, now I read that you want two captions.

Comment: @Sigur ouch haha. Thanks though!

Comment: @el_maxx: Please take a look at the example I posted

Comment: The other solution is to use a tabular.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646589/misaligned-side-by-side-pictures-how-to-resolve/646603?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C39.2403#646603 for example.

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo. I'll also try your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code with `floatrow`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx, floatrow}
    \usepackage{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \floatsetup{heightadjust=all, valign=c}
      \begin{floatrow}[2]
        \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{traccia-table}}{\caption{Meret Openheim; Traccia table \label{MO}}}
        \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{NightmareFussli}}{\caption{Johann-Heinrich Füssli: Nightmare \label{JHF}}}
      \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Can "Figure:" be deleted? I just want to write "(a)" and "(b)" in the captions.

Comment: @el_maxx: for that, you'll  need to use the `subfloatrow` environment  (nested in `figure`).

Comment: Thank you very much!