# How can I vertically align four different sized subfigures and their respective captions?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats, alignment, figure-placement

I want to have a Figure out of 4 different sized subfigures in one line. The subfigures should be centered vertically and the captions should be at the same height.

I tried with and without `[c]` after `\begin` subfigure the but cant get both figures *and* captions aligned.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{Gibson.pdf}
            \captionsetup{justification=centering}
            \caption*{\textbf{V}\\ Gibson \textit{et al.}\\ 2002} 
            \label{fig:s5}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Salen.pdf}
            \captionsetup{justification=centering}
            \caption*{\textbf{VI}\\ Idage \textit{et al.}\\ 2010}
            \label{fig:s6}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Fe_N_4.pdf}
            \captionsetup{justification=centering}
            \caption*{\textbf{VII}\\Herres-Pawlis \textit{et al.}\\ 2017}
            \label{fig:s7}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Thomas.pdf}
            \captionsetup{justification=centering}
            \caption*{\textbf{IIX}\\Thomas \textit{et al.}\\2001}
            \label{fig:s8}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Structures of iron catalysts used in the ROP of LA
        \label{fig:StructuresIronCat2}}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image: without use of c, captions aligned but not the figures]

without use of `[c]`, captions aligned but not the figures

[image: with use of , figures aligned but not the captions]

with use of `[c]`, figures aligned but not the captions

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: should be compilable now

Comment: To align imgaes and captions separately, one can use a tabular.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646589/misaligned-side-by-side-pictures-how-to-resolve for example.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

Like this?

[image]

One (only possible) way is to move images baseline to their vertical center and insert images in table (as suggested  @John Kormylo in his comment) with one row with vertically centered images and with the next row for (top aligned) captions.

By help of `adjustbox` this is simple to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\adjustboxset{valign=m}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\adjincludegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth,height=3cm]{Gibson.pdf}
    &   \adjincludegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=1cm]{Salen.pdf}
        &    \adjincludegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=2.5cm]{Fe_N_4.pdf}
            &   \adjincludegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=2cm]{Thomas.pdf}
                \\
\caption*{\textbf{V}\\ Gibson \textit{et al.}\\ 2002}
\label{fig:s5}
    &   \caption*{\textbf{VI}\\ Idage \textit{et al.}\\ 2010}
        \label{fig:s6} 
        &   \caption*{\textbf{VII}\\Herres-Pawlis \textit{et al.}\\ 2017}
            \label{fig:s7}  
            &   \caption*{\textbf{IIX}\\Thomas \textit{et al.}\\2001}
                \label{fig:s8}
 \end{tabularx}           
\caption{Structures of iron catalysts used in the ROP of LA}
\label{fig:StructuresIronCat2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```